# SharePoint Caml Query

Tags: caml-query

I have a SharePoint caml query that checks a SharePoint list if ReviewDate < Var_Tomorrow AND ReviewDate >= Var_Today AND ContractDuration  not = to Ad Hoc AND ContractStatus = open OR ContractStatus = empty

```
<Query> 
  <Lists> <List ID="{17B687AC-F88F-45D5-9074-1E91A9BBD3B0}" /> </Lists> 
  <ViewFields> <FieldRef Name="ID" /> </ViewFields> 
    <Where> 
      <Or> 
      <And> 
      <And> 
      <And> 
      <Geq> <FieldRef Name="Review_x0020_Date" /> <Value Type="DateTime">{WorkflowVariable:Var_TodayNoTime}</Value> </Geq> 
      <Lt> <FieldRef Name="Review_x0020_Date" /> <Value Type="DateTime">{WorkflowVariable:Var_TomorrowDate}</Value> </Lt> 
      </And> 
      <Neq> <FieldRef Name="Contract_x0020_Duration" /> <Value Type="Choice">Ad Hoc</Value> </Neq> 
      </And> 
      <Eq> <FieldRef Name="Contract_x0020_Status" /> <Value Type="Choice">Open</Value> </Eq> 
      </And> 
      <Eq> <FieldRef Name="Contract_x0020_Status" /> <Value Type="Choice">{WorkflowVariable:Var_Null}</Value> </Eq> 
      </Or> 
    </Where> 
</Query>
```

It's not returning any documents even though there is a document that meets all of the above criteria but for some reason it's not finding it.

Comment: Please share your CAML. The synopsis helps, but it's better to see the full code.

Comment: Thans Phil, here is the code

Comment: It works best to add to your original question using the "edit" button below the question. The comments section should be used to respond to other users follow-up questions and for brief discussion/clarification. I'll add the code to your question for you and format it properly.

Comment: try this link---https://dhondiyals.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/caml-query-search-between-two-date-ranges-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

Part of the query you list includes:

ReviewDate <= today AND ReviewDate > tomorrow

I don't think these conditions can be simultaneously satisfied.

Comment: sorry my mistake meant ReviewDate< Var_Tomorrow AND ReviewDate >=(greater than or equal to)Var_Today @PhilGreer